# работа с файлами в Qt linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, файлы

Всем привет.
Хочу прочитать содержимое файла /proc в Linux. Сейчас мой код выдает, что не может прочитать данный файл. Вопрос почему и как исправить. Повторюсь, хочу читать содержимое файла /proc.

```
{
  QFile FileProc("/proc");
  QByteArray DataProc;

  if (!FileProc.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
      qDebug() << "gg";
       return -1;
    }

  DataProc = FileProc.readAll();
  qDebug() << DataProc;
}
```

Comment: Это же директория

Comment: в linux всё файл так что по идее должен и её считать

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html vs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html

Comment: @Samsongoot никто такого не обещал, банальный `cat /proc` вам тоже выкинет ошибку